# How to pass or copy table field value from one table to another table using ASP.NET MVC and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have two tables named Order and Invoice_Line_Items. I have a column called "invoice_number" in both tables "invoice_number" and Invoice_Line_Items. But "invoice_number" column in Invoice_Line_Items table is empty. I need to copy the data present in the "invoice_number" column from the Order table to "invoice_number" column in Invoice_Line_Items table.

This is an example of what I want to achieve
[image: Expected result]

Comment: Looks like the relationship between these 2 tables are `Order_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue and here is the code below

1. changed the table name from order to ordering
2. the invoice_number from Invoice_Line_Items made it retrieve the maximum number from ordering table order_id

   ```
    public ActionResult SaveOrder(Order[] requesting)
   {
       string result = "Error! Order Is Not Complete!";
       using (mymodel dbb = new mymodel())
       {
           var customerId = Guid.NewGuid();
           Ordering ord = new Ordering();
           ord.CustomerId = customerId;
           ord.date_order_placed = DateTime.Now;
           dbb.Orderings.Add(ord);

           if (dbb.SaveChanges() > 0)
           {

               string order_id = dbb.Orderings.Max(o => o.invoice_number);

               foreach(var item in requesting)
               {
                   Invoice_Line_Items in_l_i = new Invoice_Line_Items();

                       in_l_i.invoice_number = order_id;
                       in_l_i.department = item.depart;
                       in_l_i.service = item.Service;
                       in_l_i.gender = item.Gender;
                       in_l_i.item = item.Item;
                       in_l_i.quantity = item.Quantity;
                       in_l_i.price = item.price;

                   dbb.Invoice_Line_Items.Add(in_l_i);

               }



               if (dbb.SaveChanges() > 0)
               {
                   result = "Success! Order Is Complete!";

               }

           }
       }

       return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the relationship between these 2 tables are `Order_id`?
This is just the example:

```
var query = from it in db.Invoice_Line_Items
        join order in db.Order
        on it.Order_id equals order.Order_id  into lg
        from order in lg.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new Invoice_Line_Items
        {
           Order_id = it.Order_id,
           Invoice_number = order == null? null: order.Invoice_number,
           item = it.item,
           quantity = it.quantity
        };
```

Comment: the invoice_number of Invoice_Line_Items table is null